# Docker : Pull images from Local git repo / hard drive

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a base docker image (Ubuntu) in Local Git Repo. Now I want to build docker image (with application jar) by pulling the base image from Git.
As I understand "FROM ubuntu:latest" pulls the ubuntu image from Docker Hub.
However, I am behind firewall and could not access Docker hub.

Is there an option to pull the base image from the Local Git/hard drive and build my own docker image without reaching Docker hub.

Any sample script, material will be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this resulting file somewhere. This example is for `ubuntu:latest` image. Use [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/):

```
docker save ubuntu:latest > /somewhere/ubuntu.latest.tar
```

But you can `gzip` it to reduce its size:

```
docker save ubuntu:latest | gzip > ubuntu.latest.tar.gz
```

Then, having that file, with [docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) you can:

```
▶ docker load < /somewhere/ubuntu.latest.tar.gz
Loaded image: ubuntu:latest
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. So "docker load" untar the tar file and loads the image. After this is done, can I have docker file like this?
     'FROM ubuntu
     ENV JAVA_VER 8
     .......
     .......
     CMD ["java","-jar","/home/git-repo/test.jar"]`    . I want the loaded base image to be picked when running "FROM ubuntu" rather than pulling from Docker hub. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The image name comes inside the tar file too, as metadata.